# Como podría filtrar una lista de referencias a otro documento en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, sql, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente modelo

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    match: /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: roles,
    default: 'user'
  },
  picture: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },

  alumnos:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'AlumnoRes' 
  }],
}, {
 
  timestamps: true
})
```

Alumnos tiene una lista de referencias al siguiente documento

```js
const alumnoResSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String
  },
  telefono: {
    type: Number
  },
  visita: {
    type: Date
  },
  empresa: {
    type: String
  },
  alumnoid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'alumno'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (obj, ret) => { delete ret._id }
  }
})
```

La cuestión es ¿Como podría mostrar la lista de alumnos de un usuario y filtrarla por nombre y empresa mediante una petición?

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

Si tienes un array con los *ObjectId* de los alumnos asociados a un Usuario, podrías hacer una consulta *más compleja* sobre el modelo de alumno. La consulta sería de tipo:

```
Alumno.find({$and: [{_id: {$in: user.alumnos}},{nombre: {$regex: 'patron'}}]})
```

De esta forma, localizaría a aquellos alumnos que estén en dicho array y cumplan el filtro.

Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

¡Hola!

Este caso lo he visto tratar más desde Android que desde la API, con la creación de un Filter.

Mira este tutorial, está muy bien explicado y seguro que te sirve para conseguir lo que quieres:

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

¡Un saludo!

Comment: disculpa que tiene que ver android con NodeJS?